# Undefined attribute name (data-local)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I am trying to internationalize my jsp page using ajax using jqueryi18n plugin but while calling the data-local and data-i18n attributes in my jsp page it is showing

> "Undefined attribute name (data-i18n)."

```html
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="switch-locale">
    <li><a href="#" data-locale="en">En</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-locale="am">አማ</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```